# chrome-devtools is Garbled ! My file encoding is GBK

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

1. It show normal before I use [add folder to workspace]
2. The new create file show garbled after I use [add folder to workspace]
3. My javascript file like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="x.js" charset="GBK"></script>`
4. My project is GBK

My project is GBK, I need you help!

Comment: Have the same problem. My project is in cp1251. I'v made bug report and hope for fix.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling workspaces in chrome devtools means that devtools will *save your changes*. Importantly, the saved file will be in unicode, regardless of what the original encoding was. This behaviour doesn't appear to be configurable. If you don't want your files converted to unicode as you update them, don't enable workspaces. I don't see any other option.

If, on the other hand, you are happy to work in unicode, don't forget to update the charset references in the meta tags.

Comment: which seems it's a promising solution.